# home URL Key Redirect

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, redirect-url

I recently notice google is indexing my site one with /home and one without. clearly this www.test.come/home URL exist but i do not see this url in my URL rewrite in the back-end. what is the best solution to remove this /home so google is not indexing the home pages

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There will be some variants available for your home page of store. In  case you have SSL there will be more 2 variants.

You can add this code in header to tell Google to use it as canonical url:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://yourdomain.com">
```

Comment: what is the path to my header in Magento 2, where do I add this line?

Comment: If you don't have them look at here vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/ otherewise check in theme

Comment: can this <link rel="canonical" href="http://yourdomain.com"> be added anywhere on the file, can I add this to the bottom of the header.phtml. ?

Comment: Yes. It will be better if you add in head file